# Put IF condition inside a variable

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, conditional-statements

Is there any way to put conditions within a variable and then use that variable in an if statement? See the example below:

```
$value1 = 10;
$value2 = 10;

$value_condition = '($value1 == $value2)';

if ($value_condition) {
    echo 'It works!';
} else {
    echo 'It doesnt work.';
}
```

I understand this may be a bizarre question. I am learning the basics of PHP.

Comment: No, you cant do that. $value_condition is just a string in the above code. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @steve I am simply curious if this type of concept works.

Comment: OK, as the numerous answers now appearing show, you can save the resulting boolean and use that. But if the question is 'will a string of php code be evaluated in a conditional block' then the answer is no.

Comment: U can hack it with `eval` but... that's just evil :-)

Comment: @Steve: absolutely wrong! Actually a string get evaluated too (in C and even in PHP). try if("0") or if("hello"). The first one get evaluated as false, the second as true.

Comment: @G_G perhaps my wording is poor, highlight should be **of php code**. I was attempting to explain that the string will not be interpreted as code, so `if("10 > 100")` will evaluate to true.

Comment: @Steve. In C you're right: there's no such string-evaluation based on the actual content of the string (only the pointer get evaluated, in fact in C a string is just a pointer to some char array). PHP does a little bit more: it actually peeks inside the string and if it found 0 (0x30 in ASCII, not the 0x00 NULL terminator) then evaluates the string as false. Even the empty string "" get evaluated as false. In PHP the only two strings that get evaluated as false are the empty string and the "0" string. :-) This PHP weirdness creates all sort of almost-unspottable bugs, IMHO!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to use strings. Use it directly this way:

```
$value1 = 10;
$value2 = 10;

$value_condition = ($value1 == $value2);

if ($value_condition) {
    echo 'It works!';
} else {
    echo 'It doesnt work.';
}
```

Or to evaluate, you can use this way using `"`, as it expands and evaluates variables inside `{ ... }`.

I reckon it might work! Also, using `eval()` is evil! So make sure you use it in right place, where you are sure that there cannot be any other input to the `eval()` function!

Comment: For the sake of completeness, you could also explicitly call eval. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: @DragonYen I don't think you need to call that as code inside `"`s is evaluated automatically and it has also been confirmed by the OP! `:)`

Comment: Can you please update your question with eval and I will mark this as correct.

Comment: @DragonYen Please, don't suggest that `eval()` is a appropriate in this situation.

Comment: @Brad Added a note to the `eval()`'s dangerous.

Comment: @PraveenKumar you second code example is just wrong and should be removed from this answer http://codepad.viper-7.com/htHyhI

Comment: @Brad I wasn't suggesting that the example given needed the use of EVAL. However the way the question is worded, gives the indication that the OP wants to evaluate an if condition from a string. Teaching them the right way to do something doesn't effectively answer the question for future people coming across this post looking to do what the original question asked. If the end result of this question is "How do I write an if statement" I would suggest that this question should be closed.

Comment: @DragonYen When you write answers to questions, you need to understand as much context as possible.  The question specifically says, "I am learning the basics of PHP."  The last thing you want to do is tell someone who is *learning the basics of PHP* that they need to put `eval()` in their code every time they want to store a bool in a variable.  And no, questions should not be closed just because they are simple questions.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you are trying to do, an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/functions.anonymous.php) could help here.

```
$value1 = 10;
$value2 = 10;

$equals = function($a, $b) {
    return $a == $b;
};

if ($equals($value1, $value2)) {
    echo 'It works!';
} else {
    echo 'It doesnt work.';
}
```

However, I would only do it like this (and not with a regular function), when you make use of `use ()`.

Answer (score 1):

`==` operator evaluates as a boolean so you can do

```
$value1 = 10;
$value2 = 10;

$value_condition = ($value1 == $value2);

if ($value_condition) {
    echo 'It works!';
} else {
    echo 'It doesnt work.';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just assign result of comparision to variable.

```
$value1 = 10;
$value2 = 10;

$value_condition = ($value1 == $value2);

if ($value_condition) {
    echo 'It works!';
} else {
    echo 'It doesnt work.';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An `if` statement tests a boolean value.  You could have something like this:

```
if (true) {
```

You can assign boolean values to a variable:

```
$boolValue = true;
```

You can use variables in your `if` statement:

```
if ($boolValue) {
   // true
```

In your example:

```
$value_condition = $value1 == $value2; // $value_condition is now true or false
if ($value_condition) {
```