# How to check if condition defined as variable in php?

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have one variable which contains the condition dynamically and I need to check that condition. For example,

```
$condition = '21 < 20';
if($condition){
    echo "yes";
    } else {
    echo "no";
    }
```

I want to check this condition but it always returns "yes" because the condition variable has some string. How can I actually check the condition that 21 is greater than 20. Can anyone pass through this kind of problem? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Put IF condition inside a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26589974/put-if-condition-inside-a-variable)

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php, I'll get my coat.

Comment: How are you building the `$condition` variable dynamically? Or better yet, what is dynamic about the condition -- if you want to dynamically change the comparison used, maybe look at a `switch` statement and then build `if` statements from there. Interested to see your requirements.

Comment: How complex can the condition be? Will it always be of the form  "number < number" or can it include an arbitrary number of conditionals, including calls to PHP functions

Comment: `$condition = '21 < 20'` is this line from your code? If so, it will always return true (in your case 'yes'), because you're passing a string to the condition and thus it is checking only if the there is any value. If you want to check if the 21 is bigger number than 20, you can type it as `$condition = 21 < 20;` without the single quotes. Or use `eval($condition)` if the string is passed there dynamically.

Comment: @Silencesys - You are right. But If I am writing that condition then I can put it wirhout string. But I have to call one function that returns me this value and I need to put it in if to check whether its true or not.

Comment: @Joni - It can be, 1)  ( '01_IM' == '01_IM' || '01_IM' == '01_XF' ) , 2)  (   (`13` = 99 )  OR  ((`13` >= 208) AND (`13` <= 209)) )

Comment: @duckboy81 - I cannot use switch condition here. This condition is generated by the other function  and I just need to check whether its true or not.

Comment: @SejalPatel Could this work for you? `$condition = yourConditionalMethod(); $condition = eval($condition); if ($condition) {..}`

Comment: @Silencesys - I tried. its not working.

Answer (score 1):

Straight from PHP.net

> **Caution**
>   The **eval()** language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.

With that said, using your requirements (and part of your code), your result will look something like this:

```
// Define the condition from the other function
$condition = '5>3';

// Grab the result of evaluating that condition
// VERY DANGEROUS IF YOU CANNOT TRUST THE INPUT
$result = eval('return ('.$condition.');');

// Execute a normal if statement check
if($result){ echo "yes";} else {echo "no";}
```

Comment: If I use eval, it just shows me my condition is blank.

Comment: Where are you running this code? Some hosts disable eval (especially if you're using a site like [http://phptester.com](http://phptester.net). What do you mean when you say it shows you the condition is blank, the result variable, condition variable?